# Evolve content over beamer slides: using `scope` to group elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, scoping

I am applying https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518585/114719 where I use `scope` to group elements while developing content over multiple beamer slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.7\paperheight}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox(-5.5,-.5)rectangle(6,5.5);%                                                                                                                                                           
      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
      \coordinate (A) at (5, 5);
      \coordinate (B) at (-5, 5);
      \begin{scope}<1->
        \draw (O) -- (B);
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}<2->
        \draw (O) -- (A);
      \end{scope}
      \draw<3> (A) -- (B);
      % \begin{scope}<3>                                                                                                                                                                                   
      %   \draw (A) -- (B);                                                                                                                                                                                
      % \end{scope}                                                                                                                                                                                        
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In case I also group elements on the last slide, replacing

```
      \draw<3> (A) -- (B);
```

with

```
      \begin{scope}<3>                                                                                                                                                                                   
         \draw (A) -- (B);                                                                                                                                                                                
      \end{scope}
```

the array of slides collapses to just the last slide. Why is this so and how can I group elements also on the last slide using `scope`?

Comment: I've add a solution at your [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518584/evolve-content-over-beamer-slides/518780#518780) that can solve the problem.

Comment: It seems like `\draw` and `scope` are not overlay specifications for `beamer`, as described in section 9 of the [manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). You should use `\uncover` or `\only`.

Comment: There is a library for Ti*k*Z that adds `beamer` overlay functionality to Ti*k*Z, it is called `aobs-tikz`, you can use it via `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}`.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis, could you provide an answer based on `\uncover` or `\only`?

Comment: @JānisLazovskis You should definitely not use `\only` unless you want to compute the bounding box by hand for every picture.

Comment: @Viesturs Sure, just do `\uncover<1->{..}` and put everything from `\begin{scope}` to `\end{scope}` in the dots `..`, similarly for `\uncover<2->{..}` with the 2nd `scope`, and `\uncover<3>{..}` with the `\draw`. There's more to type, but I think it's clearer exactly what is being shown in each frame.

@Schrödinger'scat I'll take your word for it; personally I only use `\uncover`, but a quick glance at the manual made it seem like `\only` is another similar option, so I figured I would mention it.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis Thanks! The usual problem with `\only` is that the frame jumps because the bounding box of the picture is computed on the basis of the paths that are inside of it. So if you leave out a path, the bounding box will change, and the picture jumps. This is why in the above code `\useasboundingbox` is added. But I find this extremely impractical, you have to compute it by hand, and if you later decide to add an element to the picture, you have to redo it.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis, it is better that you provide a complete answer, that compiles.

Comment: @Viesturs Done. It's not using any overlay functionality, so I don't know if it will work with any other code you may have, but it works in the example you've given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a version of a scope that gets wrapped into `\onslide`, you can do that as follows:

```
\newenvironment<>{Scope}[1][]{\onslide#2\begingroup\begin{scope}[#1]}{%
\end{scope}\endgroup}
```

Then you can use `\begin{Scope}<3> ... \end{Scope}` instead of `\begin{scope}<3> ... \end{scope}`, which is a bit wrong and does not work, as you say.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newenvironment<>{Scope}[1][]{\onslide#2\begingroup\begin{scope}[#1]}{%
\end{scope}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.7\paperheight}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox(-5.5,-.5)rectangle(6,5.5);%  unnecessary                                                                                                                                                         
      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
      \coordinate (A) at (5, 5);
      \coordinate (B) at (-5, 5);
      \begin{Scope}<1->[blue]
        \draw (O) -- (B);
      \end{Scope}
      \begin{Scope}<2->
        \draw (O) -- (A);
      \end{Scope}
      \begin{Scope}<3>
         \draw (A) -- (B);
      \end{Scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The blue line is only to show how you can add the options of the scope.

I personally still think that `overlay-beamer-styles`, as illustrated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518586/194703) and suggested by Skillmon will on the long run help quite a bit, at least I am using it a lot for precisely such applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using `\uncover`, which is used as (for example) `\uncover<1->{..}`, and everything inside the braces `{..}` is shown at <s>slide 2</s> slide 1 and onward. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} \begin{frame} \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.7\paperheight}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-5.5,-.5)rectangle(6,5.5);
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (A) at (5, 5);
\coordinate (B) at (-5, 5);
\uncover<1->{\begin{scope}\draw (O) -- (B);\end{scope}}
\uncover<2->{\begin{scope}\draw (O) -- (A);\end{scope}}
\uncover<3>{\draw (A) -- (B);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{overlayarea} \end{frame} \end{document}
```

The `\uncover` command can be nested, if you want to show a scope after (for example) slide 2, but some parts of the scope later. In your example, the above code will give the same result if you replace the three lines that start with `\uncover` with the following lines. I've added indendation to show the nesting.

```
\uncover<1->{
  \begin{scope}
  \draw (O) -- (B);
  \uncover<2->{
    \begin{scope}
    \draw (O) -- (A);
    \uncover<3>{
      \draw (A) -- (B);
    }
  \end{scope}}
\end{scope}}
```

Comment: then probably you don't need to use `scope` and you mean "at slide 1 and onward".

Comment: @Viesturs Sure, but it's your code, I'm only making the smallest necessary changes to achieve what you want :)