# Using <> beamer slide specifier for \newcommand

Tags: beamer, macros, overlays

I am using `<>` to specify slides as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518585/114719

I get in trouble when applying this specifier to a macro defined via `\newcommand` as in this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\drawline}[2]{
  \draw (#1) -- (#2);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.7\paperheight}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox(-5.5,-.5)rectangle(6,5.5);%                                                                                                                                                         
      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
      \coordinate (A) at (5, 5);
      \coordinate (B) at (-5, 5);
      \draw<1-> (O) -- (B); %OK
      \drawline<2> {A}{B}; %trouble
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{overlayarea}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The compile error is:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named < is known.
```

How can apply the `<>` slide specifier to a macro defined via `\newcommand`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make your custom macros aware of overlay specifications by using `\newcommand<>`. Inside the macro definition, an additional argument will be available that contains the overlay specification and can be passed to other macros.

In your example, you have two arguments `#1` and `#2`. Now using `\newcommand<>` instead of `\newcommand`, the overlay specification can be accessed via `#3`. You have to add it to the `\draw` as `\draw#3`. Full example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand<>{\drawline}[2]{
  \draw#3 (#1) -- (#2);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.7\paperheight}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox(-5.5,-.5)rectangle(6,5.5);%                                                                                                                                                         
      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
      \coordinate (A) at (5, 5);
      \coordinate (B) at (-5, 5);
      \draw<1-> (O) -- (B);
      \drawline<2> {A}{B};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{overlayarea}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Then it is complicated if I use a library of 100 `newcommand`s each containing 100 lines of code.

Comment: Agreed, but necessary. How should the processor otherwise know to which parts of your macros the overlay specification should apply? Imagine a macro that inserts some bold-faced text along a line - should the overlay now only regulate when to use boldface or when to draw the line at all?